# Get-PnPProvisioningTemplate Home.aspx error

Tags: sharepoint-online, pnp-powershell, template, homepage

So I have an issue while using the `Get-PnPProvisioningTemplate` comandlet... So I can go through and create lists and doclibs and pages all over a site, and create the provisioning template and that works fine.

But as soon a I change one element on the /Home.aspx page, I will get:

```
Get-PnPProvisioningTemplate : Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
At ...\SharePoint\PowerShellScripts\pnp provision\CreateTemplate.ps1:31 char:13
+             Get-PnPProvisioningTemplate -Out $ptoTemplate
+             ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : WriteError: (:) [Get-PnPProvisioningTemplate], NullReferenceException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : EXCEPTION,SharePointPnP.PowerShell.Commands.Provisioning.Site.GetProvisioningTemplate
```

I know its' the [Client Side Page Contents] section because I run my script with the `Set-PnPTraceLog -On -Level Debug` on, and if I add the flag `-ExcludeHandlers PageContents` it runs with no error. I.E:

```
Get-PnPProvisioningTemplate -ExcludeHandlers PageContents -Out $ptoTemplate
```

Even if I revert the Home.aspx to version created by the System version, it remains broken.

I am trying to build a template of a "Modern Team Site" if anyone think  that might matter.

--

Additional information, I also ran the commands:

```
Connect-PnPOnline -Url https://balhblah.sharepoint.com/sites/TemplateSite
Enable-PnPFeature -Identity 0c8a9a47-22a9-4798-82f1-00e62a96006e -Scope site
```

So that I could enable the `Content Organizer` Drop Off Library on the site.

I was really just trying to add that Drop Off lib to the Home page when I discovered this issue. Not sure if that is somehow related.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Daniel -
I'm seeing the identical behavior in one tenant but not in another tenant. I noticed a specific bug related to this logged in the PnP github, but that was specific to using some custom SPFx web parts. So that does not apply to my scenario. If I take the default modern team site, and simple edit the Quick Links web part to add a link to bing.com (to avoid the '"Home.aspx" has not been modified so there is no need to extract it' message), I still get the Null Reference error, same as with my actual site which has a few other OOB web parts. But the identical powershell script referencing

Comment: @TomCastiglia - Thanks for validating that I am not crazy, frustrating as it might be. When I first started creating these templates I was able to capture a customized Home.aspx, but was before I played around with HUB sites. I thought maybe if a site had a Hub site association (which adds a Nav bar to the top of all child hubs) that THAT might be causing this error in some form. Alas, my testing didn't confirm that. Removing site from a Hub, and trying to build template then, does not fix the issue. SHM...

Answer (score 0):

The command Get-PnPProvisioningTemplate generates a provisioning site template from a web.

The command can work for a site. It cannot work for a Home.aspx page.

Could you please provide the whole PnP script when you use the command Get-PnPProvisioningTemplate?

More reference:

[Get-PnPProvisioningTemplate.](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/sharepoint-pnp/get-pnpprovisioningtemplate?view=sharepoint-ps)

Comment: The only commands in my script: 

`Set-PnPTraceLog -On -Level Debug` - 
`Connect-PnPOnline -Url https://balhblah.sharepoint.com/sites/TemplateSite -Credential $credentials` - 
`Get-PnPProvisioningTemplate -Out $ptoTemplate`

Comment: On a fresh team site with no edites, when the `TraceLog` gets to the [PageContents], it says: -- `"Home.aspx" has not been modified so there is no need to extract it.` -- So not really sure what you mean by "It cannot work for Home.aspx page" I am tring to template the whole site. I have reviewed the pnp documentation, but am afraid it does not shed much light on my understanding of the issue.

Thanks for your response @Amy_MSFT !